# php not connecting to mysql database MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

So I have some php to connect to my database that i'am running using MAMP but it does not look to be working. This is my class.database.php (sorry the code is a bit messy). Do you guy think this is could be the problem or is it something else in my code? Thanks for the help.

```
    <?
class dbConnection {
        protected $db_conn;
        public $db_name = 'todo';
        public $db_user = 'root';
        public $db_pass = 'root';
        public $db_host = 'localhost';

        function connect(){
        try{
            $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;db_name=$this",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass)
                    return $this->db_conn;
    }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                    return $e->getMessage();
                }
        }
            }

?>
```

Comment: the *exact* error message?

Comment: how do you call the connect function?

Comment: not getting any error messages, just not adding to the db

Comment: nothing in the code does any adding

Comment: This class file is called at the top of the other files.

Comment: syntax is wrong: This is right
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
db_name=$this
```

with

```
db_name=$this->db_name
```

Also, you need to place a semi-colon at the end of that line.

With those mistakes, you should be getting PHP and PDO errors. Check your PHP logs for errors. You can also run a script from the command line using "php myscript.php" to see errors (though you'll need something to invoke your class). To display PDO errors, add this line below your "new PDO" line:

```
$this->db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
db_name=$this
```

with

```
db_name=$this->db_name
```

Also, you need to place a semi-colon at the end of that line.
This is your code and I change It . I test this code and work for me .I hope working for you .

```
<?php
class dbConnection {
    protected $db_conn;
    public $db_name = 'todo';
    public $db_user = 'root';
    public $db_pass = 'root';
    public $db_host = 'localhost';

    function connect(){
    try{
        $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;db_name=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
                return $this->db_conn;
}
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                return $e->getMessage();
            }
    }
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You syntax is wrong :

```
 try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
                                              ^^^^^^

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```